# can liquibase be used to work with two different schema versions of the db at the same time?

Tags: ios, liquibase

I'm trying to overcome the following issue...

I have a MariaDB database that is used for an IOS application.

I'm about to release a new version to the apple store that uses a different version of the schema of the database. means all achievement related tables are modified.

can liquibase be used to configure the changes and allow selected users to connect and work with the schema as if the old schema version is configured, and to actually make the actual changes to the new schema?

before I release the application I need to provide apple with a test version so they will confirm it. so I want users that are connected from apple to see the new achievements features and to work with the new schema while regular users to still be able to user to previous version of the application and to work with the old schema that behind the scenes will actually update the database according to the new schema.

I hope I explained myself properly.

can Liquibase do that ? or it's just like a git for db changes ?

thank you! :)

Comment: Has the api between your application and your server changed?

Comment: @JonRose - yes.. I plan to support both api versions on the server till the application will be approved.

Comment: Is there a fundamental reason that the old api can't read and write to the new database schema?

Comment: @JonRose - the all achievements feature was modified... i still know how to insert rows to the new schema when users use the old version of the application. I know that this can be resolve by server code but I've been told that liquibase is also being used to resolve these kind of issues. I just want to confirm that it's true